# Local Node.js script not connecting to mongoDB database

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, mlab

I setup a MongoLab MongoDB database through Heroku and am able to connect to it in the shell by issuing the below command:

```
mongo ds061701.mongolab.com:61701/heroku_app35721468 -u <dbuser> -p <dbpassword>
```

I'm using Node.js and Express and wrote the following code in a script.js file, which sits in the same directory as a node_modules folder containing mongoose.

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect('mongodb://<dbuser>:<dbpassword>@ds061701.mongolab.com:61701/heroku_app35721468');
var db = mongoose.connection;

db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'connection error: '));

db.once('open', function(){
    console.log('db connected');
});
```

When navigate to the directory of this script in Terminal and type `node script.js`, I get the following error message:

```
dyld: lazy symbol binding failed: Symbol not found: _node_module_register
Referenced from: /Users/Jack/Documents/node-express-101/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/mongodb-core/node_modules/bson/build/Release/bson.node
Expected in: dynamic lookup

dyld: Symbol not found: _node_module_register
Referenced from: /Users/Jack/Documents/node-express-101/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/mongodb-core/node_modules/bson/build/Release/bson.node
Expected in: dynamic lookup

Trace/BPT trap: 5
```

What am I doing wrong here and how can I connect to my MongoDB database hosted on MongoLab with mongoose?

Comment: Did mongoose install properly? Assuming you used `npm i mongoose --save`, did it install without errors?

Comment: I am very much new at this. I navigated to the directory with the file and used `npm install mongoose`, as instructed on the mongoosejs website.

Comment: I just installed it again using `npm i mongoose --save` and it seems to be working. Thank you! Why should I have installed mongoose this way and why did the script not work when installing mongoose with `npm install mongoose`?

Comment: they're both the same command. `npm i` is short for `npm install`. Without seeing the original install output we can't know why it didn't install properly.

Comment: Should I always include `--save` when installing dependencies?

Comment: I think I exited the mongoose install process before it was complete because it seemed like the shell just wasn't doing anything.

Comment: If you want `npm` to be able to help you reinstall easily (`npm i` will install everything you have saved), checking for out of date dependencies ('npm outdated`), etc. then yes you would want to do so. You should at the least check out npm's [documentation](https://docs.npmjs.com/). As for exiting an install: never assume it installed correctly at that point as that is not the expected behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Referring to [comments from OP's original question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29568608/local-node-js-script-not-connecting-to-mongodb-database?noredirect=1#comment47286974_29568608): the solution was the original dependency install did not complete successfully. Reinstalling solved it.

Answer (score 0):

That error will be thrown when you have installed modules (that require compilation) with Node 0.12, but subsequently try to run those modules with an older Node version (like 0.10).